# Convergence Weak Operator topology implies Convergence in Ultraweak topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

If we want to show that $T(x_n)$ converges ultraweakly to $T(y)$ in some Banach space $X$. Given $\sup_n \{  \|Tx_n \|\} \le \| Ty \|$, is it enough to show that $T(x_n)$ converges weakly to $T(y)$?

I know that the weak operator topology is stronger than the ultraweak topology. But I'm not sure if the above is true.

Thanks in advance!